# Docker/CI: Get access to nodeJS app, which is created in another stage

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab-ci

In my CI pipeline (gitlab) there is a **build** and an **end2end-testing** stage. In the build stage the files of the application will be created. Then I want to copy the generated files to the e2e_testing container to do some tests with this application.

How do I copy the generated files (/opt/project/build/core/bundle) to the image?

For e2e testing I want to use nightwatchJS - see the e2e docker image below. Maybe it is possible to use the build image within the e2e image?

What I need to do is nightwatchJS e2e testing for the generated nodeJS application

---

**My attempt**

Copy the generate files to `e2e_testing` container with `docker cp` command.

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - meteor build /opt/project/build/core --directory
  script:
    - cd /opt/jaqua/build/core/bundle
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
  after_script:
    - docker cp /opt/project/build/core/bundle e2e_testing:/opt/project/build/core/
```

But this is not working, as the next stage (e2e) will create a container from the `e2e:latest` image. So in this container there is no bundle folder existing, so this sample script is failing.

```
e2e:
  image: e2e:latest
  stage: e2e
  before_script:
    - cd /opt/project/build/core/bundle && ls -la
  script:
    # - run nightwatchJS to do some e2e testing with the build bundle
```

**e2e:latest image Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8-jre

## Node.js setup
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

## Nightwatch
RUN npm install -g nightwatch
```

A container called `e2e_testing` is created from this image and it is running all the time. So at the time the CI pipeline is running, the container is already existing.

But at the time, this image is created the application files are not existing, as they are generated at the build stage. So I cannot put those files in the docker image using a Dockerfile.

**So how can I get access to the files generated in the build stage in the e2e stage?**

Or is it possible to use the build image ($CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest) within the nightwatch image (e2e)

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31257

Comment: @johnharris85 I don't see, which part you want to show me... :-(

Comment: What application is parsing these yml files? I.e. what CI tool are you using?

Comment: These two sentences seem to conflict, I may be misreading: "But this is not working, as the next stage (e2e) will create a container from the e2e:latest image." and "A container called e2e_testing is created from this image and it is running all the time." Is the container always running, or is the image regenerated and container recreated at each run?

Comment: @BMitch I am using gitlab CI. And right now the container is recreated each run. Don't know how to set it up correctly to get the test running for the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts)?

Basically move the bundle folder to the root of your repository after the build and define the bundle folder as an artifact. Then, from the e2e job, the bundle folder will be downloaded from the artifacts of the build stage and you will be able to use its contents. Here's an example of how to do this:

```
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - meteor build /opt/project/build/core --directory
  script:
    # Copy the contents of the bundle folder to ./bundle
    - cp -r /opt/project/build/core/bundle ./bundle
    - cd /opt/jaqua/build/core/bundle
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bundle

e2e:
  image: e2e:latest
  stage: e2e
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - mkdir -p /opt/project/build/core/bundle
    - cp -r ./bundle /opt/project/build/core/bundle
    # - run nightwatchJS to do some e2e testing with the build bundle
```

I don't know if you still need the `docker build` part, so I left it in there in case you want to push that container somewhere.

Comment: Why do I have to copy the folder to root? Isn't it possible to set the artifacts with the original path?

Comment: If you have a look at the artifacts documentation linked in the answer, you'll see this: "You can only use paths that are within the project workspace."